# Change permissions in centos automatically

Tags: linux, bash, permissions

I have a site (many files and folders) and I need to change the permissions to default.
Files: 644 and Folders 755 .   Now I have 666 for files and 777 for folders.
I can not do it manually because I have many folders that include folders and files etc.

My OS is  Centos so I can run a bash shell script.

How can I change those permissions automatically ?
Any code will be welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found! Just run the following:

`find /path/path -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;`

`find /path/path/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;`

Comment: dont forget to accept your own answer!

Comment: How is this automatic? You have to run this manually every time you want to do it.

Comment: yes, it manual but you dont have to change the permissions to every file manual.. You simple run this comamnds and its ok.. If you want to do full automatic just do a cronjob with that commands..

Answer (score 3):

You can combine your solution into a single `find` command. This should be about twice as fast because it won't have to walk the filesystem twice.

```
find /path/path -type d -exec chmod 755 {} + -o -type f -exec chmod 644 {} +
```

Ending the command with `+` instead of `\;` is also more efficient. Instead of running the `chmod` command separately for each file, it bundles up all the filenames into a long argument to a single execution (although if the argument is too long for a single execution, it will split them up optimally).

If you want to do this automatically, you could put it into a `cron` job that gets run periodically.

Answer (score 1):

A not very well documented but highly useful feature of Gnu `chmod` is that you can use the symbolic permission `X` instead of `x`. `x` simply represents the executable permission, whereas `X` represents the executable permission if (a) the target is a directory or (b) the target is a file and one of the executable permissions is set.

This lets you do the following:

```
chmod -R u=rwX,go=rX /path/to/directory
```

which will recursively (`-R`) set the permissions of all directories and executables to `rwxr-xr-x` and the permissions of all regular files to `rwxr--r--` (that is, 0755 and 0644 respectively).

Another example: Suppose you have some project with executables which are currently only accessible to you. (So the permissions are currently `rwx------` or `rw-------`). Now you want to make them readable, searchable (for directories) and executable (for executables) to members of the group `pundits`:

```
chgrp -R pundits /path/to/the/project
chmod -R g+rX /path/to/the/project
```

Now the directories and the executables are `rwxr-x---` and the other files are `rwxr-----` (and also, all the groups have been changed to `pundits`).

Answer (score 1):

We can set a cron to do this task.

```
 (make sure the /root/permission.sh should be 755)
 # cat /root/permission.sh
 #!/bin/bash
 /bin/find /path/to/change -type f -not -perm 644 -exec chmod 644 {} \; >/dev/null 2>&1
 /bin/find /path/to/change -type d -not -perm 755 -exec chmod 755 {} \; >/dev/null 2>&1
```

every 5 minutes cron:

```
 0 */5 * * * /root/permission.sh
```